# Is there a limit of connections for DbContextFactory

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, quartz.net

I have a quartz job that makes multiple queries to the db.

I'm using DbContextFactory that provides a DbContext for each query.

I noticed that for big tasks where they will be thousands of queries application starts to throw the following exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.ScopedLoggerFactory.Create(IServiceProvider
> internalServiceProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions)    at
> ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext ,
> ServiceProviderEngineScope )    at
> ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext ,
> ServiceProviderEngineScope )    at
> ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext ,
> ServiceProviderEngineScope )    at
> ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext ,
> ServiceProviderEngineScope )    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet1.get_EntityType()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet1.get_EntityQueryable()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
> at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable1 source,
> Expression1 predicate)

Another clue is this doesn't happen in a debug mode.

Is there some kind of connections limit in DbContextFactory ?